# Bash Shell Expansion Issue with multiple \r

Tags: bash, shell, vim, quoting

I am trying to batch fix some .scc files using vim and need to pass a substitution sting to it.

I'm trying to use `vim -E` to pass this line `":s/\r/\r/g"`

I've tried embedding individual characters as a variable within the quotes but the `\r` messing it up.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to replace `\r` with `\r`?

Comment: This sounds like a possible instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/172535). What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: also I do need to use vim in the next pass as I need to apply ":set fileformat=dos to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at what you really want to do as it doesn't sound like a one-off change. The following will remove all `\r`s.

---

**NOTE**  it does an inplace edit - no need to redirect etc.

---

```
 perl -i.bak -p -e 's/\r+//g' filename(s)...
```

If you want to replace it with a single `\r` do

```
 perl -i.bak -p -e 's/\r+/\r/g' filename(s)...
```

Perl will keep a backup but so should you.

It's not using `vim` but then perhaps you shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you must use `\n` in the search part and `\r` in the replacement part. But replacing `\n` with `\r` sounds a lot like doing nothing to me.

Anyway, launching Vim just for a substitution is probably a bit too much. You could use `sed`:

```
$ sed -i.orig 's/foo/bar/' foo.txt
```

Read `$ man sed` for more info.

Comment: The issue is we get files for PC's presumably mad on Macs and the \r represent carriage return.  But since they're not properly formatted the PC reads the file as a singe line with "^M" where the returns should be.  The issue with sed it that I think it's ignoring the ^M's.

Answer (score 0):

got it.  ':s/\\r/\\r/g'

I just needed the right level of quotation. The issue as I touched on earlier is that we get files that include PC double line breaks presumable made on a mac and the PC's can't read them properly.

So using sed to s/\r/\r\n/g wasn't really working for some reason, and maybe I could explore it more.  But I think passing these to vim will help. I must use vim to send :set format=dos to the file.

Thanks all.